# ISP glitch or a malware? Has this ever happened to you?

Tags: windows, malware, dns

**Brief background:** I consider myself a relatively paranoid power-user, if not an absolute pro. I regularly update my AV and keep up with all the latest updates on my Windows 7 machine. But what happened today surprised me for the first time.

Today morning at around 13:30 India time, I opened www.google.com in my Firefox 32 browser. But instead, my browser forwarded me here:

**WARNING!! POTENTIAL MALICIOUS SITE:** `http://demo.opera-mini.net/public`

Tried with IE 11, the same result.

Then I did a `ping www.google.com` and browsed using that IP address instead. It worked and took me to Google India site.
I then opened the `.co.in` instead of `.com` site, that too worked!
I went to a vm inside VirtualBox (Ubuntu/Firefox) and browsed from there instead. That too worked!

At this point, I disconnected my machine from internet and ran a complete AV scan. It came up clean. Then I tried the only logical thing that occurred to me: Clearing the browser cache for google.com domain. I did it on IE and lo! it started working. On Firefox, I didn't have to do that either, it started working on its own (though I don't understand why).

After that brief anomaly, I faced no issues until now. So what do you hackers make of this situation? Could it be a malware issue or something from my ISP end?

Comment: Which type is your Internet connection?

Comment: Its mobile broadband (dongle)

Comment: Could be a case of DNS poisoning and cached DNS entries.  Disconnecting from the internet might have cleared some of those cache entries.

Comment: Is there a way to find out whether it certainly happened or not? More importantly, how do I detect and/or prevent it from happening the next time?

Comment: Did someone else use your computer and go to an unsafe site, possibly?  And if so, is your browser set to "pick up where you left off?"

Comment: @Ian - Not a possibility, since I don't allow anyone to touch my machine. However, the culprit turned out to be a flash plugin as I mentioned in a different comment below. Don't know how/when it got installed, but I removed Adobe Flash as I didn't have any real need of it.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, flash plugin was'nt the culprit, since the issue occurred even afterwards. Weirdly however, it has abruptly stopped happenning since a month or so! Mysterious!

Comment: *It's mobile broadband* configure your computer to use some trusted DNS resolvers like OpenDNS or Google's DNS. For some reason mobile carriers are very disrespectful in terms of net neutrality and I wouldn't be surprised if they poisoned your DNS records to advertise a mobile browser (that's what Opera Mini is).

Comment: @André - That's horrible! That's blatant violation of a user's online rights, not just being disrespectful in terms of net neutrality.

Comment: @PrahladYeri you know what's worse ? They install transparent HTTP proxies that alter content in transit, like compressing images for example. In my country I've seen someone complain they couldn't see new responses to a forum thread by just opening it (they had to explicitly press F5 again), and it was clear evidence such a proxy was installed and was tampering with the cache control headers.

Comment: I got hit by the exact same one with airtel connection. `curl www.google.com` gives a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://demo.opera-mini.net/public"/>` . I changed connection to vodafone, and did the curl call again, and the response was proper.

Comment: Are you using airtel connection by any chance ?

Comment: @BoopathiRajaa - Yes precisely! I no longer use Airtel, but was using it when this issue had occurred. This was the issue with Airtel network, maybe some of their DNS servers were misbehaving. This problem resolved itself the moment I stopped using Airtel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're either behind a malicious proxy/VPN or your host file is effected. Most likely the latter.

On windows 8 you can check your hosts file here

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Remove any lines with strange IPs. Infact you can remove everything if you aren't running any cracked software or have routes setup for a web server.

This could also be DNS poisoning on your local network, so be sure that's secure too.

Comment: There was nothing in the hosts file, I already checked. However, this again happened a second time, and this time I opened the task manager to see what .exe processes were running. And sure enough I saw two Flash plugins at work! This was despite the fact that Flash was disabled in Firefox and IE. I immediately uninstalled Flash as I had no real need and that was the end of this. I'm never going to install Flash again!